# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments > [directory 'libs']

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android App Development. I am trying to create an Android app using TabLayout and have added the following dependencies in the `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But on running the App, I am getting build error as follows

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [directory 'libs'] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>                 Consult IDE log for more details

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Change compile fileTree to compile files. This should work.

Comment: Do you have any library files to include in your project other than the dependencies given?

Comment: No. I am just trying to use the TabLayout, so I have added this dependency. Before that I tried a simple App without TabLayout. It was working fine

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 build.gradle.
 - android/build.gradle
 - android/app/build.gradle

In my case moving dependencies to the 2(android/app/build.gradle) worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it happened because of the way I did gradle and kotlin updates.

In my case inside android->gradle folder
of my project there were two different versions of gradle, by deleting one it was possible to run the project normally.